# How to identify the value of an unmarked SMD capacitor on a PCB?

Tags: capacitor

I have an unmarked SMD capacitor on a PCB and I want to identify the value of this SMD capacitor. I have an LCR meter (BK880) and I want to use it to measure directly the capacitance of this SMD capacitor.

Do I need to discharge the SMD capacitor before measuring it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to desolder it from PCB before you can measure it, as capacitors cannot be measured in-circuit. And discharge it too, but a multimeter can be used to measure if it is already discharged.